# Lost ability to send bulk email

Tags: civimail

I am the new coordinator for Huntingdonshire Green Party (previously I was the deputy coordinator), My wife is the membership secretary. Until tonight, both of us were able to access Civi and send emails to the membership & supports of our local party (Huntingdonshire Green Party). Tonight, we cannot.

The only difference is that we have both drifted into "grace" membership (by accident and both of us has resolved this by re-subscribing) but I as we have the Civi roles, I would not expect that to affect our civi access level.

Is this the issue? Or is their a wider issue?

[image: image of menu available]

Regards,
James Goodman

Comment: Hello James, and welcome to Stack Exchange!  This is a question that can only be determined by reviewing the permissions configuration - and based on your menu, you don't appear to be an administrator, so you don't have access to it.  This seems like a question for someone in your organization with administrator rights.  Feel free to have them repost the question with screenshots of the permissions/ACL screens if they're stumped!

Comment: I note this is the second 'general support' request from someone In the GP of England and Wales - and I wonder if there is an issue that your internal documentation is not providing instructions on who to reach out for these type of internal problems. Not saying 'don't ask here' but both have been more specific to the GP EW imo.